# Einstein engagement frequency not able to find the data

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein

I have a few years of send history and millions of contacts/subscribers in one of my Business Units... Einstein Engagement Frequency is stating that there is "No data to estimate Einstein Frequency Suggestions."

Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

Comment: Is the psmain automation running in the EID and how many activities does it have?

Comment: I dont see anything like this or similar running... Should I contact support in this case?

Comment: This automation only exist at the top level (parent/EID) search for psmain